# Grails application with Google Account Sign in

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, google-signin

I am currently working on a Grails application and we want users to be able to sign in with their Google accounts. I am currently exploring spring-security-core 1.2.7.3 in conjunction with spring-security-openid 1.0.4. I have followed many tutorials and the best one I have found so far is this one :

http://softwareengineering101.wordpress.com/2013/05/07/integrating-grails-2-with-spring-security-openidgoogle-single-sign-on/

Unfortunately I don't think this addresses signing in with a Google account, and rather using their openID to sign in.

Does anyone have examples or tutorials of grails projects that allow users to sign in with their Google accounts?

Comment: does grails oauth plugin not work for you?  http://grails.org/plugin/oauth.  Do you need to use spring-security?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peter Ledbrook created an app to submit talks for the Groovy & Grails eXchange conference in London, and it has support for Google logins. The source is here: https://github.com/pledbrook/talk-submissions

Comment: Is there an example of one being used with Shiro and OAuth? The ":shiro-oauth:0.2" plugin page is a little hard to follow. Do I still need "compile :shiro:1.2.0"? And to run shiro-quick-start?

Comment: Shiro? Never heard of it ;)

Comment: When I use shiro 1.2 with shiro oauth 0.3, I have to login with shiro first and then it sends me to the google log in

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [shiro ouath plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/shiro-oauth). It has support for google oauth, and would let you authenticate using google accounts.

Comment: I have been following this method, but it doesn't seem to do anything.  I have set oauth/provider/google as follows : google{
            api = GoogleApi
            key = 'key'
            secret = 'secret'
            scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
            callback = "http://localhost:8080/moment/oauth/google/callback"
            successUri = "http://localhost:8080/moment/oauthCallBack/google"
        }but when I click on my sign in button,it links me to http://localhost:8080/moment/auth/login?targetUri=%2Foauth%2Fgoogle%2Fauthenticate but never does anything

Comment: Try enabling logging and see if it logs any errors, I believe you have properly configured the oauth plugin.

The generated link url would be like
http://localhost:8080/moment/oauth/google/authenticate?redirectUrl=foo

You should be able to use
<oauth:connect provider="google">Connect Google account</oauth:connect>